# Image and new section on the same page

Tags: graphics, sectioning, positioning

I want an image to be at the top of the page and the new section to start below the image on the same page. I tried to position the image using [t] but nothing changes. The image appears in the center of the page and the new section starts on the new page... How can I fix that?

Here is my code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[MeX]{polski}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[small]{caption}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\title{zzz}

\author{zzz}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\section{A}\label{sec:a}

\begin{figure}[h]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{a.jpg}}
\caption{xxxx}
\label{label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{a.jpg}}
\caption{xxxx}
\label{label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{a.jpg}}
\caption{xxxx}
\label{label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{a.jpg}}
\caption{xxxx}
\label{label}
\end{figure}

\section{B}\label{sec:b}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Please add a `minimal working example (MWE)` that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editors and work with it, as well as to see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Did you try forcing the position with a `!` like this: `\begin{figure}[!h]`?

Comment: The LaTeX expect that in normal circumstances (using default settings) tha page consist at least 30% of text other scan be floats. In your case you have only floats. Also use only `[h]` specifier not enable flexibility in placing of floats. Off-topic: using `\makebox` does not help in anything to inserting of images. You can/should omit all of  them.

Answer (score 2):

After:

- reducing your example to the minimum (I'm keeping `lmodern` because it doesn't have the same metrics as Computer Modern);
- replacing all `\begin{figure}[h]` with `\begin{figure}[ht]` (the LaTeX output told you it was already working in this way anyway);
- removing the useless `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{...}` calls (your `\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{...}` already creates a box that is `\textwidth` wide);
- using images present in all TeX installations (if you want to include images with precise dimensions here to allow us to reproduce your problem, use something like `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=1cm]{example-image}`, or similar with `example-image-a`, `example-image-b`, etc.);
- removing all useless (here) and duplicate labels (read the LaTeX output!),

one arrives at:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}

\title{zzz}

\author{zzz}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{A}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{xxxx}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{xxxx}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{xxxx}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{xxxx}
\end{figure}

\section{B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This doesn't strike as incorrect figure placement...